# Azure region not listed in some subscriptions when creating new Azure SQL server

Tags: azure-sql-database, bizspark

We have a handful of Azure subscriptions through the Bizspark program.  Some of our subscriptions allow creating new Azure SQL Servers in the "US West" region but others do not.

The Azure status page does not show any availability issues.  The closest I found to an answer was [this post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1ab9fc7e-d953-4430-8594-2b48ddbfdfd1/sql-database-server-not-available-in-canadian-regions?forum=ssdsgetstarted) from mid-December where the last answer hints that there may be region restrictions when a subscription is linked to an MSDN benefit.

Can anyone confirm the above restriction?  If so, why would it impact some subscriptions and not others if they were all created via Bizspark?  Is this a new restriction so older subscriptions were not affected?  Is there any way to have the restriction removed?

Comment: I think the comment that you linked to is definitive. It was posted by a Microsoft employee.

Comment: I would suggest you open a support ticket directly in Azure Portal since the issue looks specific to some of your subscriptions.

Comment: As the employee who posted the comment you're referring to, there are some similar restrictions on bizspark subscriptions- the inconsistency is unexpected, however. Filing a support ticket would give the necessary information for our engineers to look into your situation.